# How to use SVN in ios 6?

Tags: ios, svn

I am new to use SVN in iOS 6.Can anybody give me the steps which i follow it.Simply my quiz is How to use SVN in IOS6 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for an SVN client for iOS? Or do you want to use SVN for an iOS project? Please clarify.

Comment: Can't imagine using a versioning system on a system where applications cannot access files of other applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow these steps:

- Open your XCode
- Select File-->Source Control-->Repositories

[image: Menu option]

- Configure your repository in this window (To add a repository select the **+** button on the bottom of the left pane)

[image: Config]